# (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query)

Tags: python, mysql, timeout, mariadb

I am having problem querying to a MariaDB database that is hosted on a Virtual Machine. I am using the dataset Python module.

This is my code:

```
import dataset

db = dataset.connect("mysql+pymysql://....")

Q = "select * from mytable Limit 1"

print(db.query(Q))
```

However I would get this error message:

> (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server
>   during query ([WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
>   established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond)') (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

I have tried to configure the timeout variables such as; connect_timeout, wait_timeout etc within the my.cnf file and sending a very simple query, but the issue still exist.

Any solutions or suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Your datetime format might be not correct, try to run the query directly on your database without python, your condition isnt valid datetime format.

Comment: @Aaron Hi, I've updated my post. It errors on any query that I've sent. Thank you

Comment: I've managed to get a work around using **mysql.connector** python module to send a query to my database. However, I am still curious on why using the **dataset** python module is not working

Comment: Does the error occur during connect or when sending a SQL statement? Maybe some error handling would be helpful.

Comment: @GeorgRichter The error occurred when I am sending a query **db.query(Q)**.